What do these parts of Hecate's speech in Act 3 scene 5 from Macbeth mean?
The lines are the following:

How did you dare
to trade and traffic with Macbeth …
(…)
shall draw him on to his confusion.
He shall spurn fate, scorn death, and bear
his hopes 'bove wisdom, grace, and fear.
And you all know, security
is mortals' chiefest enemy.


The lines essentially mean the following:

How did you dare
have dealings with / conspire with Macbeth …
(…)
shall draw him on to his ruin.
He shall despise fate, scorn death and cherish
his hopes beyond wisdom, fate and fear.
And you all know over-confidence / the absence of anxiety
is the main enemy of mortal beings.

